# Follow up purchase query in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a membership database that I'd like to extract purchase information from, but I'm not sure of the best way in SQL. We sell subscriptions, which are entry passes into our gym for fixed periods of time, eg. 3 months. Members buy them and when they expire they may buy another. We'd like to select a group of members, eg. students who bought a 3-month pass some time ago, and determine what their next subscription purchase was, if any.

There are three tables (with relevant columns) involved:

- SubscriptionTypes(ID, Description, Duration) - defines what subscriptions can be purchased
- Subscriptions(MemberID, SubTypeID, StartDate, EndDate) - instances of purchases, links a member with the subscription types they have purchased over time
- Members(ID, Type) - member data, where Type can be Student, Standard, Pensioner

So if I wanted to determine the IDs of members who bought a 3-month subscription at this time of year last year, I could use something like:

```
SELECT MemberID, StartDate, EndDate
FROM Subscriptions s
INNER JOIN Members m
ON s.MemberID = m.ID
INNER JOIN SubscriptionTypes st
ON s.SubTypeID = st.ID
WHERE s.StartDate BETWEEN <period start> and <period end>
AND m.Type = 'Student'
AND st.Duration = 3
```

This gives me the set of members (and the actual start and end dates of the passes they bought last year).

But how do I go from this starting point and then extract the next subscription purchase for these members in the period (say 1 month) after their 3-month pass expires. I can come up with *procedural* methods, eg. iterate over each member in the set above and run a query, but that's not the SQL way.

Can anyone give me some direction? I'd like to finish with the set of members from the original set, their first purchase subscription info and their second (if any).

Answer (score 2):

Since you are on SQL Server 2005, you have the power of [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) available to you. I would suggest starting with something like

```
SELECT MemberID, StartDate, EndDate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MemberID ORDER BY s.StartDate ASC) 
        AS SubscriptionSequence
FROM Subscriptions s
INNER JOIN Members m ON s.MemberID = m.ID
INNER JOIN SubscriptionTypes st ON s.SubTypeID = st.ID
WHERE @PeriodStart <= s.StartDate
AND m.Type = 'Student'
```

This will give you, for each `Student` member who has a subscription starting on or after `@PeriodStart`, a row for **every** subscription, along with a sequence number indicating the date ordering.

So if someone took a 3-month then a 1-month, you'd get

```
TheMemberId    Jul 1 2011    Sep 30 2011     1
TheMemberId    Oct 1 2011    Oct 31 2011     2
```

Either in further query refinement, or in application code, you can consume the sequence number as you wish.

---

Explanatory notes:

The conceptual behaviour is this:

1. Identify all the purchases that meet the `WHERE` condition (ie, were made after a certain date)
2. Group them by member (that's the `PARTITION BY`)
3. Within each per-member group, order the purchases by date, and note the position within that group (that's the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ... ORDER BY )`)
4. Emit a row for each purchase, with one of the columns being the position within the ordered per-member group (this is `SubscriptionSequence`)

If you're only interested in members who **did** make a follow-up purchase, you could do

```
SELECT MemberID, StartDate, EndDate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MemberID ORDER BY s.StartDate ASC) 
        AS SubscriptionSequence,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Subscriptions ss 
                     WHERE @PeriodStart <= ss.StartDate
                     AND ss.MemberID = m.ID) AS SubscriptionCount
FROM Subscriptions s
INNER JOIN Members m ON s.MemberID = m.ID
INNER JOIN SubscriptionTypes st ON s.SubTypeID = st.ID
WHERE @PeriodStart <= s.StartDate
AND m.Type = 'Student'
AND SubscriptionCount >= 2
```

where I have used a **correlated subquery** to include in each row a column counting the number of qualifying subscriptions made by the member referred to in that row.

Example output for member ids 234 and 567:

```
234   Jul 1 2011    Sep 30 2011     1     2
234   Oct 1 2011    Oct 31 2011     2     2
567   Jul 1 2011    Sep 30 2011     1     3
567   Oct 1 2011    Oct 31 2011     2     3
567   Dec 1 2011    Dec 31 2011     3     3
```

Here member 234 had two qualifying subscriptions, whereas member 567 had 3. A member who only had one qualifying subscription would not appear in the output of this second query, because of the final term in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm still trying to get my head around it. Can you tell me, will there be a row if a student buys a 3-month pass and that's it (ie. no second purchase)?

Answer (score 0):

It's big but you can do something like this:

```
SELECT m.MemberID, s.StartDate, s.EndDate
FROM Subscriptions s
INNER JOIN Members m
ON s.MemberID = m.ID
INNER JOIN SubscriptionTypes st
ON s.SubTypeID = st.ID

INNER JOIN (SELECT m.MemberID, s.EndDate
FROM Subscriptions s
INNER JOIN Members m
ON s.MemberID = m.ID
INNER JOIN SubscriptionTypes st
ON s.SubTypeID = st.ID
WHERE s.StartDate BETWEEN a.EndDate and dateadd('m', 1, a.EndDate)
AND m.Type = 'Student'
AND st.Duration = 3) a on a.MemberID = m.MemberID

WHERE s.StartDate BETWEEN dateadd('m', 4, <period start>) and dateadd('m', 4, <period end>)
AND m.Type = 'Student'
```

With your select, you make another equal select but with a inner join on it. With the inner join you get the members that you want to test and the enddate of their voucher. So, you can use that Enddate on the outer query.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. A couple of questions: (a) you refer to n.MemberID on line 1, should that be m.MemberID?; (b) you refer to a couple of columns with "a." as the prefix, where is "a" defined? (c) does this omit students who purchase a 3-month pass but nothing else, ie. it only selects those who make a second purchase?

Comment: a) yes, I've edit. b) is the inner query (I made an alias on it) c) yes, only select the ones who made the second. The inner query (with alias a) selects the members that bought the pass, the outer query selects, from those members, who bought another